# How can i find where my node.js app crashes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nginx, amazon-ec2

Here's the thing: I created a node.js app and mongodb and deployed on Amazon EC2.

By crashed I mean: It wasn't possible to access the app.

Node.js Server -> Nginx, EC2 m3.large, PM2 module with cluster (2 vCPU)

Mongodb Server -> EC2 t2.micro

My problem: 
Yesterday, the app reached 600 concurrent connections, then it crashed. When I checked pm2 status, both CPUs app processing was 1.50gb

Running pm2 restart all , 2minutes later everything was working again.

Question(s):

Where is the best point to start digging? Mongodb max connections ? Nginx ? Node.js app handling connections wrongly ? EC2 servers not enough CPU ?

I really need some help here. 
Thanks !

Comment: How did you start the node process?  There should be a stack trace on `stdout`.

Comment: Do you have logs from PM2?  This would have been passed to PM2 when you started the Node app.  Something like "pm2 start -n $name -p $pidFile -o $logFile $nodeApp".

To find the log, execute:

    `pm2 list`

Note the id of your app from the output and then execute:

    `pm2 desc <id>`

Check-out the file paths under "error log path" and "out log path".

Comment: Yes, i think it's something with mongodb: http://pastebin.com/hKs7xbqQ